# Get raw A-frame code from scene

Tags: aframe

I am working on a A-Frame IDE based on [Ace](https://ace.c9.io/).
The editor validates, if the written HTML-code is correct, and if so, I just innerHTML the code into another div to render the scene. This direction of "editing" works.

What I want / cant get to work: 
If I now move an object in the scene using e.g. the A-Frame inspector,
I cant get the resulting plain A-Frame code to display the manipulated values in the editor.
Is there a way to get plain A-Frame code from a scene to implement a complete sync of an IDE and the result?
Thanks!

[image: A-frame editor]

Answer (score 2):

Use the `debug` component cf https://aframe.io/docs/0.5.0/components/debug.html . It flushes to the DOM the attributes. Note you can also call it programmatically using `document.querySelector('a-scene').flushToDOM(true);` if you want to hide that from the user.

Here is a basic example http://jsbin.com/nuwoxu/edit?html,output

```js
AFRAME.registerComponent('toeditor', {
  init: function(){    
    this.flushToDOM(true)
    console.log(this.el.innerHTML
      .replace(/<canvas.*/,"")
      // clean the injected canvas
      .replace(/\w+="" /g, ""))
      // clean empty attributes, using defaults
  }  
});
```